# What is the XPATH expression for this

Tags: php, xpath, html-table

I've a html file and want to locate the table(among many) with second TH content of "Stn Code" and 3rd TH content of "Route No.". What will be the XPATH expression in php to get this particular table:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="heading_table_top">
            <th width="6%">SNo</th>
            <th width="9%">Stn Code</th>
            <th width="17%">Stn Name</th>
            <th width="9%">Route No.</th>
            <th width="9%">Arrival Time</th>
            <th width="9%">Dep. Time</th>
            <th width="15%">Halt Time (In Minutes)</th>
            <th width="9%">Distance</th>
            <th width="6%">Day</th>
            <th width="20%">Remark</th>
```

..................................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will find the table with the specified content regardless of which `th` the content contains:

```xml
//table[descendant::th="Stn Code" and descendant::th="Route No."]
```

> The [descendant axis](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) contains the descendants of the context node; a descendant is a child or a child of a child and so on; thus the descendant axis never contains attribute or namespace nodes.

[demo](http://codepad.org/ZdaJ1FGR)

If you want to make sure the content is in specific `th` elements, use `th[n]` where `n` is the position, e.g. for the *"second TH content of "Stn Code" and 3rd TH content of "Route No."*. you'd use `th[2]` and `th[3]`. Positions are 1-based.

```xml
//table[descendant::th[2]="Stn Code" and descendant::th[3]="Route No."]
```

Note that in your example markup "Route No." is in `th[4]` so the above XPath will not produce the table in the result nodes.

[Also have a look at this XPath tutorial](http://schlitt.info/opensource/blog/0704_xpath.html).

Comment: Thanks but in my web page this table is wrapped under many tables and all are getting returned. I want only one with immediate descendant of this th texts.

Comment: This looks to be working: $dom_xpath->query('//table//tr[th[2]="Stn Code" and th[4]="Route No." and th[7]="Halt Time (In Minutes)"]/parent::*');

Comment: @user774250 try `//table[tbody/tr/th[2]='Stn Code' and tbody/tr/th[4]='Route No.']`

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
//table/tbody/tr[th[2]='Stn Code'][th[3]='Route No.']/../..
```

Edit: my first expession selected the tr element, this should select the table.